# MySQL Query Help - Using != with ANY

Tags: mysql

I have the following query (MySQL):

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM database1.table 
  ->WHERE col3 != ANY(SELECT col1 FROM database2.table) 
  ->ORDER BY this, that;
```

And I had hoped this would allow me to select col1 and col2 from a table in database1 where col3 (still in database1) does not equal anything from col1 in a table in database2.

Naturally, this wont work because SELECT col1 FROM database2.table returns more than one row, so if is equal to row1, then it's not equal to row2 so it's still returned.

Any thoughts on how to do this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT IN`

> SELECT col1, col2 FROM database1.table 
>     ->WHERE col3 NOT IN(SELECT col1 FROM database2.table) 
>     ->ORDER BY this, that;

but keep in mind that subselects are not optimized in MySQL, and if there are a lot of records in database1.table this would be slow. Faster way is to use `JOIN` - there are a lot of examples at SO

Comment: I didn't know that subselects aren't optimised in MySQL. Does that mean, there isn't a query transformation facility, that transforms the `NOT IN` operation into an anti-join, if the necessary constraints are available?

Comment: when you are performing `IN (SELECT ...)` MySQL performs the inner select for each row found in the outer one (instead of performing the inner select just once, before the outer)

So you have to write SELECT  col1, col2, a.col FROM database1.table  LEFT JOIN (SELECT col1 AS col FROM database2.table) as a ON(table.col3 = a.col1) WHERE col IS NULL

Comment: @Lukas you are lucky guy :p there are a lot of things you whould not care, compared to when using MySQL.

Comment: @Darhazer: I know, but believe me, there are other problems :) +1 for the important performance hint though!

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE col3 NOT IN (SELECT col1 FROM database2.table)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use NOT IN operator for this
SELECT col1, col2 FROM database1.table 
  ->WHERE col3 NOT IN(SELECT col1 FROM database2.table) 
  ->ORDER BY this, that;

Answer (score 0):

Just use ALL instead of ANY:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM database1.table 
WHERE col3 != ALL(SELECT col1 FROM database2.table) 
ORDER BY this, that;
```